# How many string objects are created?

Tags: c#, string, object

I have the following C# code:

```
string stg1 = "String 1";
string stg2 = "String 2";
string stg3 = "String 3";
string stg4;
stg4 = stg1 + stg3;
stg4 = stg4 + stg2 + stg3;
stg4 = "";
stg3 = "";
```

How many string objects are created?
I think 7 string objects are created: `"String 1"`, `"String 2"`, `"String 3"`, `stg1 + stg3`, `stg4 + stg2 + stg3`, `""`, and `""`. I wasn't sure if the 4th statement (`string stg4;`) creates a string object and I read somewhere that assigning a string the empty string `""` doesn't create an object but I don't think that's true. What do you guys think?

Comment: A string is created just once, so both `string.Empty` will reference the same string in the intern pool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Comment: @StevenBakhtiari Does it matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I read somewhere that assigning a string the empty string "" doesn't create an object but I don't think that's true. What do you guys think?

That's not quite true.  There is most certainly a string instance created for an empty string.

Having said that, there won't be two instances in that code; there will be just one.  Unless you disable the setting when compiling, the compiler will find all compile time literal strings that are identical and create just one `string` object to represent it and give all variables that defined that string the same reference to that one string.  This is called "interning".

Note that, by default, string interning is only done for *compile time* literal strings, not strings generated at runtime.  If, at runtime, you generate two strings that are equal, they won't necessarily be references to the same string object.

Other than that, your analysis is correct.

It's also worth noting while you were correct in stating that `stg4 + stg2 + stg3` will result in the creation of just one string, you didn't really explain why, and it's not obvious why that's the case.

An initial guess might be that there would be two operations performed here, first `stg4 + stg2`, which would result in a string, and then that result would be concatenated to `stg3` to create the final result.  That is not the case though.  The compiler will *actually* generate a *single* call to `string.Concat`, passing in all three strings as arguments (`Concat` is defined as `Concat(params string[] args)` so it can accept any number of strings) and `Concat` is smart enough to create just one string, rather than creating strings for the n-1 intermediate values.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx): _"the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared **or created programmatically** in your program"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Strings that are created programmatically are not automatically interned; `object.ReferenceEquals("AB", String.Concat("A", "B"))` is `false`. That's what the [Intern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) method is for.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's *possible* to intern strings that are created programmatically, which is why that statement is there, but it is not enabled by default.  Likewise, you can choose to not intern compile time literal strings.  Note that the *purpose* of `string.Intern` is to intern a string created at runtime.  If all strings created at runtime were always interned, such a method would have no purpose.

Comment: @Servy: makes sense, thanks. However, something like this is interned automaticlly: `"Hello" + " " + "World` as `"Hello World". That's what MSDN means with _programmatically_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That's not an example of *interning*, that's an example of *constant folding*. Interning is when you have the same literal twice, `"abc"` and `"abc"`, and they are reference equal at runtime. Constant folding is the compiler doing the work on the constants at compile time instead of letting the runtime have the fun.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Since that string will actually be combined into "Hello World" *at compile time*, rather than at runtime, that's not even an example of a programmatically generated string.  Yes, it will be interned, but that's because it is still a compile time literal (the compile time concatenation happens before the interning).

Comment: Thank you, you guys have been very helpful.

Comment: One other note about the `Concat` call: there is an overload that has a `params` parameter, but there are actually overloads that accept 2, 3, and 4 `string`s/`object`s as well (presumably because those are the common cases, and will be slightly more performant since the array creation isn't necessary.)

Answer (score 6):

Servy's answer is pretty much spot on; I particularly like the correct analysis of the concatenation.

I would simply add to that excellent answer one small additional point, and that is that it is implementation-defined whether or not the non-literal `String.Empty` is interned with the literal `""`.  Some versions of .NET do and some do not intern it automatically.

See

http://ericlippert.com/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/

for more details.